# VS Code automatically add changes to Local Repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for Git. When I open my local git repository on my system using the VS Code, there are some changes that are automatically added and it says that I made some changes. Check the Image:

[image]

I don't know how these changes are being made. I have to restore these files every time and it again appear next time I open VScode. Below are the changes that are being added:

[image]

I Above Image, the Base URL and Path is getting added.

[image]

In the above image, the Path is different.

I am new in GIT and any help would be appreciated.